# Condition on two random variables

Tags: conditional-probability, conditioning, conditional-independence, conditional

I'm trying to set up the proper assumptions for a proof I'm working on:

Given that $P(A|e) = P(A)$ and $P(A|c,e) = P(A|e)$, can we prove that $P(A|c)=P(A)$?

I understand that A is independent of e and A is also independent of c given e, thus we can say A is independent of c.

I think this is relatively trivial to prove but I can't just give it out. Do I miss any assumptions to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement is true. You can use the fact the fact that you can obtain a marginal probability by taking the expectation of a conditional probability, i.e.
\begin{align*} 
\mathbb{P}(A \mid C=c) &= \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{P}(A \mid C =c,E) \mid C=c] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[P(A) \mid C =c ] \\
&= P(A). 
\end{align*}
This is the breakdown of each equality

- The first equality holds by integrating the conditional probability. To see the intuition for why, suppose that $E$ is discrete
  $$ \mathbb{P}(A \mid C =c) = \sum_e \mathbb{P}( A \mid C = c,E=e)\mathbb{P}(E = e \mid C = c) $$
- The second equality substitutes the relationship in your problem.
- The third equality uses the fact that $\mathbb{P}(A)$ is a constant.